# Bounce email count is always 0 with Sitecore Email Cloud

Tags: exm

I am using EXM with Sitecore 8.2. I have issue with bounce count which is always 0. I am using Sitecore Email cloud (sparkpost). Looking forward for the advice to fix this. Thanks

Comment: I have checked this question but it is about custom SMTP (not email cloud)

Comment: Its not a duplicate question as Sitecore email cloud has different way to deal with bounce.